# Scale picasso bitmap to fill height in CircleImageView

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I'm using a https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView library, but also tried several others and it didn't help. I need to load image from server with picasso, like this `mPicasso.load(url).into(mCircularImageView)`. However I always get this: [image]

But I need to achieve this:

[image]

Tried to call `resize(100,100)`, `fit()`, `transform(new CircleTransorm())`,

```
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

nothing of the above helped.

My layout:

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_profile_picture"
        style="@style/ProfilePicture"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Style:

```
<style name="ProfilePicture">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/profile_picture_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/profile_picture_size</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/profile_picture_placeholder</item>
    <item name="civ_border_width">1dp</item>
    <item name="civ_border_color">#FF000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

White `fit()` defers the call until the view is loaded and measured, it does not achieve the results that you want. You need to add `centerCrop()` in order to achieve the expected output:

```
mPicasso.load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(mCircularImageView)
```

Comment: Then make sure your layout is set up correctly. Could you update your original question with your layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

Just set this attribute to your circleimageview

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

This should do it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

please use this you can create dynamic imageview, i hope this will help you.

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add any library for circular image view.
Android api already provides

> [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)

to use for this purpose. I have used [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to do what you want -

```
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.color.gray)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView){
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing in your code is you are using both circle transformation and circle image view. for make circle you have to use only one approach, I am suggestion go with circle transformation also change your circle image view to simple image view.

```
mPicasso.load(url).resize(300,300).centerCrop().transform (new CircleTransform ()).into(mImageView);
```

hope It will help.